# how to do a javascript validation in joomla backend

Tags: javascript, joomla

How to do a java script validation in joomla?

Answer (score -1):

Same was as on the Front-End, by using `JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');`

Here is [Joomla's tuturial for adding validation](http://docs.joomla.org/Form_validation). Only difference is that you will have to copy the CSS for `invalid` class, it highlights the textboxes when values are not valid.

Also, my personal preference. Instead of coding the `<form ... onsubmit="return jsFunction()">` I like to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready', function(){

// Add submit event to the form
$('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e){
    // Default check
    var isValid = document.formvalidator.isValid(frm);

    // Do additional checks + create message
    var msg  = '';
    if (!isValid){
        msg = 'Some values are not acceptable. Please retry.';
    }else if($('some-other-value').value == 0){
        msg = 'Select IO';
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (!isValid){
        // Stop event
        new Event(e).stop();

        // Somekind of invalid form handler... can do effects in here, etc...
        handleInvalidForm(this, e, msg);
    }

    //
    return isValid;
});


});

</script>
```